# PostgresError about statement syntax in postman using deno-postgres

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, deno

Creating a deno app http server from a crash course, with Oak and deno-postgres modules , i'm trying to add some data to postgre, everything works fine until send data to database.  I get 500 interval server error in Postman :

Json response in Postman after post request:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": "PostgresError: syntax error at or near 'table'"
}
```

my code :

```ts
import { Client } from "https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.14.3/mod.ts";
import { dbCreds } from '../config.ts'
//deno run --allow-net --allow-read --allow-env server.ts
// Init client
const client = new Client(dbCreds)

const addProduct = async ({ request, response }: { request: any, response: any }) => {    
    const body = await request.body()
    const product = body.value 

    if (!request.hasBody) {
        response.status = 400
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: 'No data'
        }
    } else {
        try {
            await client.connect()

            const result = await client.queryObject("INSERT INTO table (name,description,price) VALUES ($1,$2,$3);", 
            product.name,
            product.description,
            product.price)

            response.status = 201
            response.body = {
                success: true,
                data: product
            }
        } catch (err) {
            response.status = 500
            response.body = {
                success: false,
                msg: err.toString()
            }
        } finally {
            await client.end()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it the right syntax to insert data with deno-postgres?

I'm using postgres@v0.14.3 and oak (https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts)

Comment: Is the name of the table actually `table`? If so that name is a [Reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and can't be used. If it is not the name, then I would suggest looking at the Postgres log to get the full error message.

Comment: yes i named the table, table

Comment: if the table name of postgres is wrong i get a message with this code. I also tried to use previous version of postgres, like the @v0.5.0 one where .queryArray is simply query, but for this i get also 500 error with ""msg": "Error: Unknown auth message code 10". So i tried also to downgrade oak version to fit with the course but same result

Comment: Then at some point you or the client you where using did `CREATE TABLE "table" (...)`. Now you have to double quote the name whenever you use it, `INSERT INTO "table " ...`. Two options 1) The best one. Rename the table to not be a reserved word. 2) Double quote the name whenever you refer to the table in a statement.

Comment: i did option 1 and it worked i get 201 status created ! thanks a lot, but now when i go to pgAdmin to see the table, rows are created but values are null

Comment: I found my last issue, i had to add an await before body.value